# Local SI Remoto NO Stream

Tags: stream, play

Necesito de alguien me explique porque este stream solo me trabaja php de forma local y como hacer para que me trabaje en un server remoto.

Si ejecuto este PHP en Player como VLC me funciona de maravilla, pero al momento de subirlo a mi hosting no me trabaja. Pense que se trataba de la GEO localizacion y prove con otro Hosting teniendo el mismo resultado.

Logrando que esto funcione lograre re arrancar otros proyectos que tiene situaciones similares.

Gracias

```
ob_start();
//error_reporting(0);
header('Content-type: text/plain');

function m3u8($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8',
'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
'Connection: keep-alive',
'Host: hochu.tv',
'Referer: http://hochu.tv/',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'));
$server_output = urldecode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close ($ch);
return $server_output;
}
function m3u82($url2,$ideee)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8',
'Connection: keep-alive',
'Host: cdntvnet.com',
'Referer: http://hochu.tv/'.$ideee.'.html',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'));
$server_output = urldecode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close ($ch);
return $server_output;

}
function search($string, $start, $end){
    $string = " ".$string;
    $ini = strpos($string,$start);
    if ($ini == 0) return "";
    $ini += strlen($start);   
    $len = strpos($string,$end,$ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
$t= htmlspecialchars('olala');
$stream=m3u82('http://cdntvnet.com/'.$t.'.php',$t);
$streamurl=search($stream,'file:"','"});').'&type=m3u8';
$streamurl_par=parse_url($streamurl);
$hoster=$streamurl_par['scheme']."://".$streamurl_par['host'].":".$streamurl_par['port']."/".$t."/";
$geturl=m3u82($streamurl,$t);;

$part = explode(chr(10), $geturl);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($part) - 1; $i++) {
  if (strpos($part[$i], '#') !== false) {
    echo $part[$i] . chr(10);
    } else {      
      echo  $hoster.($part[$i]).PHP_EOL;  
      }
    }
```

Comment: El server remoto puede tener alguna restriccion para usar `curl`. Puedes verificar haciendo un script sencillo que obtenga un archivo y ver si muestra los datos.

Comment: Si, trate con echo $geturl=file_get_contents($streamurl); y con fopen y con ambos con el resultado similar.